# how to make pannel's height with position relative grow

Tags: html, css

Here is my problem:

`PNlmain` is the main panel in which tourists details written

`pnlTouristInfo` - holds the data for one tourist. As in the system you can make reservation only for up to three tourists  - height is 32%.   `PnlMai` holds `pnlTouristsInfo`.

`pnlName` and `pnlCharge`s holds the info for the name and the charges for a tourist. they fill up the whole space of `pnlTouristInfo`.

So the tourist can have only one name - but he can have a lot of Charges - that's why I have `pnlChargesItem`.

**The problem is - if the tourist fills a lot of extra charges how to make `pnlCharge`s and `pnlNam`e grow.So if they grow also `pnlTouristInfo` and `pnlMain` should grow relatively. Also if the tourist for example adds only one charge I want to save the `min-height` of 32% of `pnlTouristInfo`**

Sorry fr the question but I hate css - and I'm new to it

```
    .pnlMain {
        width:90%;
        min-height:50%;
        height:50%;
        border-top:solid 3px blue;
        margin:auto;

    }

    .pnlTouristInfo {
        position:relative;
        width:99%;
        min-height:32%;
        height:32%;
        border: solid 2px RGB(204,204,204);
    }
    .pnlNames
    {       
        position:relative;
        width: 28.5%;
        height:99%;
        border-right :solid 0.8px RGB(204,204,204);

        float:left;
        text-align:left;

    }


    .pnlCharges {

        position:relative;
        width: 71%;
       height:99%;
        /*border:solid 1px RGB(204,204,204);*/
        float:right;

    }



   .pnlChargesItem {

        position:relative;
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        border-bottom:0.8px solid  RGB(204,204,204);
        text-align:left;
        float:left;

    }

    .pnlChargesName {
         position:relative;
        width: 84%;
        height:100%;
        border-right:0.8px solid  RGB(204,204,204);
        text-align:left;
        float:left;
    }
    .pnlChargesPrice {
         position:relative;
        width: 15%;
        height:100%;

        text-align:left;
        float:right;
    }
```

Comment: Now how it is related to C

Comment: sorry - it was from hurrying up to write

Comment: create a jsfiddle for us, so we are all working from the same point, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height property, keep only min-height(browsers the % property are understanding differently at the vertical position, so don't use for padding-top,padding-bottom,(min)-height,margin-top,margin-bottom,etc the %).